# prueba.js:75 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Tags: php, html, jquery, bootstrap

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/popper.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/pace/pace.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/viewport/viewportchecker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>');</script>

<!-- CORE JS FRAMEWORK - END --> 

<!--datos cargados desde bosstrap-->
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/datatables/js/dataTables.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/datatables/extensions/TableTools/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/datatables/extensions/Responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/datepicker/js/datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/daterangepicker/js/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/daterangepicker/js/daterangepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/timepicker/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/alert/dist/sweetalert2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jspropios/post_jsonhistoricfactura.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jspropios/prueba.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Esto está cargando mi footer, cuando trato de cargar un modal desde jQuery me genera el siguiente error:

> prueba.js:75 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

le quito la siguiente linea al footer:

assets/plugins/datatables/js/dataTables.min.js"  type="text/javascript">

y ahí si me carga el modal correctamente

pero pues me deja de funcionar los datatables

y no he encontrado el error en concreto no se si el datatables me está cargando jQuery dos veces o como puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: Intenta usando la versión más reciente de jQuery o revisa la tabla de compatibilidad de datatables: https://datatables.net/download/

Comment: Lo solucione actualizando el datatables que tenia en el momento